# JavaScript function to play audio file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like a clean way to to write a JavaScript function that fires at a specific click to a `#div` element and triggers a sound file, without looping. Is there anyway to write a function that grabs a sound file, plays it and then stops. It is going to be apart of a large array of functions that exist per click, and are assigned to a custom number of clicks done by the user; at one specific `#main_div` button.

Currently I have a solution that displays a 'Play Button' using `.show .hide` within a function.

**JS:**

```
function function8() {
    $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
    $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
    $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0); // This one 
// I would like the above to directly play the sound when fired. Not overlay a new play button.
```

Mark-Up:

```
<div id="sound1"><div>
<audio id="id1" src="01.mp3"></audio>
<button onClick="document.getElementById("id1").play()">Play</button>
<button onClick="document.getElementById("id1").pause()">Stop</button>
</div></div>
```

But this requires an extra 'Click' to play; and also I don't want a button specific to this audio play. I would like this to exist via the main `#main_div` box button; where all of the functions will occur when clicked on; essentially I want; say Click = 3 to 'Play Sound File' automatically without requiring an extra step.

Comment: This is a little unclear... So you want to make the `<audio>` element play, but without clicking anything? Are you wanting to do this without `<audio>` elements?

Comment: Just wondering, why two divs? Does that really serve any purpose?

Comment: Also, yeah, it's really unclear what you're trying to do. Could you maybe pseudocode it for us?

Comment: or make http://jsfiddle.net/ for us

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So instead of showing a play button, which plays an `<audio>` element `onclick`, you want to just play the `<audio>` element?

Well you already have the JavaScript. You just need to call it in your function.

```
function function8() {

    // this code shows some areas
    $("#area1").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);
    $("#area2").hide(0).delay(1500).show(0);

    // this code hides the sound player and control buttons
    $("#sound1").show(0).delay(1500).hide(0);

    // this is the same line you have bound to your play button
    // it simply plays the audio element
    document.getElementById("id1").play();
}
```

In addition, you are using jQuery! So no need to `document.getElementById` craziness.

```
$("#id1").get(0).play();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this function to play sounds when things collide into each other. You can see an example of it at http://www.jellyrobotics.com/2013/01/16/box-2d/.  The overlapMax variable is to allow for multiple iterations of the sound file to be played at once. In other words, you can start playing it again before the previous instance finishes.

```
var JellySoundInstace = 0;
var JellySound = function( audiofile )
    {
    // should be optional variable because not all objects have the ability
    // to play multiple times and possibly overlap. For example, the explosion sound
    // from a single tank blowing up will only play one time for that tank instance
    //
    var overlapMax = 3;


    // PRIVATE instance variables here
    //
    var tracks = new Array();
    var soundID = "jellysound" + JellySoundInstace++;
    var track = 0;


    this.load = function( audiofile )
        {
        var i;

        for ( i=0; i<overlapMax; i++ )
            {
            var object = null;

            if ( ieVersion(8) )
                {
                object = document.createElement('div');

                var iesound = '';
                iesound = iesound + '<object id="'+soundID+'track'+i+'" type="audio/x-wav" data="'+audiofile+'" width="200" height="16">';
                iesound = iesound + '<param name="src" value="'+audiofile+'" />';
                iesound = iesound + '<param name="volume" value="2" />';
                iesound = iesound + '<param name="autoplay" value="false" />';
                iesound = iesound + '<param name="autostart" value="0" />';
                iesound = iesound + '<param name="pluginurl" value="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" />';
                iesound = iesound + '</object>';

                object.id = soundID+'track'+i+'div';
                object.innerHTML = iesound;
                object.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                object.style.position = 'absolute';
                object.style.left = '0px';
                object.style.top = '0px';
                }
            else
                {
                object = document.createElement('audio');
                object.setAttribute('id',soundID+'track'+i);
                object.setAttribute('src',audiofile);
                }

            document.body.appendChild( object );

            var newsound = document.getElementById(soundID+'track'+i);

            // needs to be handled with a method & params
            //
            newsound.volume = 0.02;

            tracks.push( newsound );
            }
        }


    this.play = function()
        {
        if ( tracks.length==0 )
            return;

        if ( ieVersion(8) )
            {
            tracks[track].Play();
            track++;
            track%=tracks.length;
            return;
            }

        tracks[track].play();
        track++;
        track%=tracks.length;
        }

    this.load( audiofile );

    return this;
    }

function ieVersion( iecheck )
    {
    if ( !(/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) )
        return 0;

    var ieversion=new Number(RegExp.$1) // capture x.x portion and store as a number

    return (ieversion <= iecheck);
    }

// Sample Usage
//
var collisionSound = new JellySound( "dink.wav" );

collisionSound.play();
```